# SQL - Duplicate entry by X copies using procedures?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, loops, duplicates

We've tried to set up a trigger with procedure that would

1. first search for an existing item by its ISBN (!!ISBN!!)
2. determine its new barcode, not its table ID (!!Item_BC!!)
3. add an identical prefix (!!Item_BC!!)
4. Insert into the table
5. repeat this till the desired amount is reached (!!X_Copies!!)

**the procedure `importISBN` looks like this**:

```
@expl_notice = select notice_id from notice WHERE code=!!ISBN!!;
DECLARE @var1 BINARY_INTEGER := !!Item_BC!!;

BEGIN
WHILE @var1 <= (!!Item_BC!!+!!X_Copies!!) LOOP

SET @Item_BC = ((!!Item_Prefix!!)+ CAST(@var1 AS CHAR))

INSERT INTO exemplaires (expl_id, expl_cb, expl_notice)  
VALUES ('','@Item_BC','@expl_notice');

END WHILE;
END;
```

**The trigger is:**

```
CALL importISBN("!!ISBN!!",!!Item_BC!!,!!X_Copies!!,"!!Item_Prefix!!");
```

a Second tryout run with a different approach:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS importISDN;
SET @noticeID = (SELECT notice_id FROM notice WHERE code = ISBN);
  SET @maxID = barCode + nrCopies;
  WHILE barCode < @maxID DO
    SET @newBarCode = CONCAT(prefix,barCode);
    SELECT @newBarCode;
    INSERT INTO exemplaires (expl_id, expl_cb, expl_notice);
  END WHILE;
END;
```

What to you think we did wrong?

Comment: So what are you trying to do, create duplicate entries, copy duplicate entries and what are you trying to get us to fix?

Comment: yes thats much about it, I tried to create duplicates with increasing items barcodes till the desired amount is reached but I never used procedures before, perhaps it can be done directly with mysql thou

Comment: Could you post up the procedure declaration so that I we can see what data types you're using for ISBN and barcode please.

Comment: Hi ChrisBD & thanks for the time you take...Well I declared var1 to be the first barecode: DECLARE @var1 BINARY_INTEGER := !!Item_BC!!;
and searched for  the existing ISBN with select notice_id from notice WHERE code=!!ISBN!!;

Comment: Anyone else? got stuck there...

Comment: I'm putting something together based on assumptions of some datatypes. I don't have MySQL installed, only SQL Server, so you may have to change some syntax. People will be confused as to the table data types.

Comment: no problem, I'll correct them to fit. its worse a try!

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure exactly what you're after and so I've broken my answer down into stages.
Note: I do not have MySQL installed on my machine and so the syntax is Transact-SQL for SQL Server.

BINARY_INTEGER is an Oracle 32bit int data type I believe.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spImportISBN]
(
    @ISBN int
    ,@NumberOfCopies int
)
AS
BEGIN
    /*if no copies to be made then exit*/
    if @NumberOfCopies<1 
    begin
        return(0);
    end

    declare @NoticeID int
            ,@MaxID int
            ,@NewISBN int
            ,@NewBarcode nvarchar(16);

    set @NoticeID = (select notice_id from Notice where code = @ISBN);
        /* if no record found then exit with error code*/
    if @NoticeID is null
    begin
        return(10);
    end

    set @MaxID = @ISBN + @NumberOfCopies;   
    set @NewISBN = @ISBN;   
    while @NewISBN < @MaxID
    begin
        set @NewISBN = @NewISBN + 1;
        set @NewBarcode = convert(nvarchar(16),@NewISBN);       
        insert into [ISBNTest].[dbo].[exemplaire] (expl_barcode, expl_notice)
                    values (@NewBarcode, @NoticeID);

    end
END
```

I was then running it using:

```
USE [ISBNTest]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[spImportISBN]
        @ISBN = 123400000,
        @NumberOfCopies = 10

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

ISBNTest was my test database.

My tables were defined as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[exemplaire](
    [expl_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [expl_notice] [int] NOT NULL,
    [expl_barcode] [nchar](16) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_exemplaire] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [expl_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Notice](
    [notice_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [code] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Notice] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [notice_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```